# ARDRONE is not responding to the ros - python code

Tags: logging, ar.drone, rospy

I tried to run my python code on the real drone but I am getting the below error and the drone is not flying.

**Unable to initiate TCP/IP socket to kathirdrone-VirtualBox:55800 (http://kathirdrone-VirtualBox:45968/):

TransportInitError: remote error reported: received a connection for a nonexistent topic [/clock] from [TCPROS connection on port 55800 to [127.0.0.1:58036 on socket 8]] [/forward]**

**Drone is flying in tumsimulator perfectly** with roslaunch cvg_sim_gazebo ardrone_testworld.launch.

**My package structure is this. catkin_ws / src / mycode / scripts / DroneFly.py**

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the launch file.

roslaunch ardrone_autonomy ardrone.launch

After the above command, connection is made.

And rosrun mycode

It works finally and the drone is flying